# What do I need proof for sufficient funds for traveling in Czech Republic?

Tags: czech-republic

I'm a US passport holder. Next month I'm planning to visit Prague to see my girlfriend and I'm hoping to be there from beginning of July to end of August. I'm going to buy roundtrip tickets at once but I don't know if they will ask for sufficient finance. If they do, what can I use as proof and how much will I need? I thought I could get something signed from my girlfriend and her family to be able to suffice for me but is that even possible?

Comment: I am from the US

Answer (score 1):

For US Citizens who are traveling to the Czech Republic for up to 90 days as a tourist or for business purposes [do not need a visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/czech-republic.html).

However, to answer your question [directly](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-application-requirements/means-subsistence/):

> Generally, there are several recognized ways to prove your financial
>   sufficiency:
>
> A personal bank statement indicating your financial movements (for at
>   least 3 last months)
>
> Credit card
>
> Cash
>
> Traveller’s cheques
>
> Pay slips
>
> Proof of employment
>
> Supporting document to attest sponsor’s readiness to cover your
>   expenses during your stay
>
> Proof of prepaid accommodation
>
> Document about accommodation in private
>
> Proof of prepaid transport